# IntelliJ - How to use same tool window location for all projects?

Tags: intellij-idea

I moved some tool windows around, for example Structure shows on right instead of left. When I open a new project, everything goes back to default. I tried to export settings from one but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window | Store Current Layout as Default